# getCurrentActivity is not public 'com.facebook.react.bridge.React Context` cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to build `react-native` module that require pass the `Activity` to some method

```
private ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

...

@ReactMethod
public void sendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber)
{
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,                            // Phone number to verify
            60,                                     // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,                       // Unit of timeout
            reactContext.getCurrentActivity(),      // Activity (for callback binding)
            callback);                              // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

}
```

I used `reactContext.getCurrentActivity()` to get the current activity from  but it tells me that `getCurrentActivity()` is not public and cannot be accessed from outside package

> getCurrentActivity is not public 'com.facebook.react.bridge.React
>   Context` cannot be accessed from outside package

**how could I get the current activity ?**

full code :

```
public class FirebasePhoneAuth extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule
{
    private ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
    private OnVerificationStateChanged callback;

    public FirebasePhoneAuth(ReactApplicationContext reactContext)
    {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return "FirebasePhoneAuth";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void sendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber)
    {
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,                            // Phone number to verify
                60,                                     // Timeout duration
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,                       // Unit of timeout
                reactContext.getCurrentActivity(),      // Activity (for callback binding)
                callback);                              // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks

    }

}
```

Comment: What is your RN version? In RN 0.47.2, `getCurrentActivity()` is a public method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the class `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` already have method `getCurrentActivity()`

code :

```
public class FirebasePhoneAuth extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule
{
    ...

    @ReactMethod
    public void sendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber)
    {
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();

        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,
                60,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,                      
                activity,
                callback);

    }

}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, just that my class extends ViewGroupManager <ViewGroup>, do you know how I can fix?